# Trying to understand UI asynchronous calls

Tags: c#, user-interface

So I found this blog post

http://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2009/01/23/synchronizing-calls-to-the-ui-in-a-multi-threaded-application/

And I've spent the morning trying to learn from it. 
It updates a single label with the "stock quote".

`MessageBus.Register<QuoteMessage>(m => label1.Text = m.Symbol+":"+m.Quote.ToString("n2"));`

I would like to update more than one label with just one message handler.  Specifically I might want to change a different label depending on what is in the QuoteMessage object.  Given the code below, I can only update the labels with a handler per label.

Doing

```
MessageBus.Register<QuoteMessage>(m => label1.Text = m.Symbol+":"+m.Quote.ToString("n2"));
MessageBus.Register<QuoteMessage>(m => label2.Text = m.Symbol + ":" + m.Quote.ToString("n2"));
MessageBus.Register<QuoteMessage>(m => label3.Text = m.Symbol + ":" + m.Quote.ToString("n2"));
MessageBus.Register<QuoteMessage>(m => label4.Text = m.Symbol + ":" + m.Quote.ToString("n2"));
```

just gets me 4 labels displaying the same thing.

Comment: Okay, so what do you *want* to do?  You know how to update one label with one value, you know how to update 4 labels with 1 value, what *don't* you know how to do?

Comment: Well, what do you expect it to display?

Comment: Its pretty obvious to me that those would all be identical, why do you think it wouldn't be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are missing is that the handler can have logic in the delegate action.  I would do something like this:

```
MessageBus.Register<QuoteMessage>(m => {
    if (m.Symbol == "MSFT") {
        label1.Text =  m.Symbol+":"+m.Quote.ToString("n2");
        label2.Text =  m.Symbol+":"+m.Quote.ToString("n2");
    }
    else if (something) {
        // Do something else
        label3.Text =  m.Symbol+":"+m.Quote.ToString("n2");
    }
});
```

Comment: 100% what I didn't realize. Thank you.

Comment: I realized I also didn't fully comprehend the lamda expression used.